# grep for a partial string, within a file

Tags: unix, grep, aix

I need to find all instances of the postal abbreviation for Idaho in a flat text file, that are preceded by exactly four characters, and followed by any number of characters.  Obviously, wildcards don't work, but this is what I am looking for:

????ID*

I know I should know this, but I'm just not getting it.

These did not work:

```
grep "[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z]ID" filename
grep '^[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][I][D]*' filename
grep '^[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z][I][D]$' filename
grep ....ID* filename
grep "....ID*" filename
```

What am I forgetting?

'root' requested example input, and desired output.  My apologies for not including that, sooner:

INPUT:

```
servername HDKSIDJIELSJ more stuff
servername LKAIIDKEJAHHLL more stuff
servername SLKERILELLWELKM more stuff
servername WOIERISLKJD more stuff
servername LQOEIDLKJV more stuff
servername POCEIDLKEKJSH more stuff
servername SLKENCLEISJEHJ more stuff
servername LSKESCIEHAL more stuff
```

OUTPUT:

```
servername HDKSIDJIELSJ more stuff
servername LKAIIDKEJAHHLL more stuff
servername LQOEIDLKJV more stuff
servername POCEIDLKEKJSH more stuff
```

Comment: Try `grep '^....ID'`

Comment: Please add example input and desired output.

Comment: root, I have added the requested input and output.

Comment: Corrected the entries.  I had left out the "servername" field in the data entries.

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: Wiktor: Unfortunately, my version of grep(I'm stuck in AIX 5.3) does not recognize the -o flag.  However, I was able to make the "grep '^....ID'" work, by increasing the number of '.' characters in the statement, and going from there.  Thank you very much, however.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to extract the first 4 alphanumeric chars and then `ID` from the start of lines.

Use

```
grep -o '^[[:alnum:]]\{4\}ID' filename
```

See the [online `grep` demo](http://s=%2212ABID%20More%20text...%20MNDFID%20another%20line...%20Nothing%20here%22;%20grep%20-o%20'%5E[0-9a-zA-Z]%5C%7B4%5C%7DID'%20%3C%3C%3C%20%22$s%22;):

```
s="12ABID More text...
MNDFID another line...
Nothing here";
grep -o '^[[:alnum:]]\{4\}ID' <<< "$s";
```

Output:

```
12ABID
MNDFID
```

Here, `-o` makes `grep` output only matched substrings, and the POSIX BRE pattern matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[[:alnum:]]\{4\}` - four alphanumeric chars
- `ID` - an `ID` substring